# HTML in textarea is not interpreted by chrome and mozilla?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

When setting the html for textarea, the line break `<br/>` works fine in IE
But in chrome and safari its comes at text.

```
<textarea id="txtMessage" cols="20" rows="20" readonly></textarea>

$('#txtMessage').html(msgText);
```

Comment: The value of a `<textarea>` is just text.

Comment: [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) > The HTML <textarea> element represents a multi-line plain-text editing control.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `.val()`:

```
$('#txtMessage').val(msgText.replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, "\n"));
```

Comment: And that works how? the value property is most definitively a string, and does not parse HTML.

Comment: problem with \n is that it misses out when passed to a javascript from a hyperlink click, its missed out from string. And when i inspect element which has javascript function call doesnt have \n in the paramater instead has a special invisible character which is lost when passed

Comment: that looks okay, msgText.replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, "\n")

Comment: but its adding <\a> after first line

Comment: what is msgText value??